# Why does Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlParser fail to parse a simple valid expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-parser, scriptdom, tsql-parser

We are using **Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom** heavily to process some SQL scripts.

Our understanding is that the parser is supposed to be full fidelity.

However, we recently found this bug:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;

var parser = new TSql150Parser(true);

string expr = @"IIF( (IIF(1 = 1, 1, NULL)) IS NULL, 1, 0)";

var res = parser.ParseExpression(new StringReader(expr), out var errors);

bool isSuccess = errors.Count == 0;
```

**Expected result**: isSuccess is true

**Actual result**: isSuccess is false

Running the following query in SQL server works: SELECT IIF( (IIF(1 = 1, 1, NULL)) IS NULL, 1, 0)

So we would expect the parser to be able to parse it as well.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: 1) Have you tried adding ELECT to the statement before sending it to the parser, does that change anything?
2) What is the value of errors.count if not 0?
3) Have you looked at the errors returns? 3.1) If not, why not? 3.2) If so, what are the error messages sent back?

Comment: SELECT is not required because I use .ParseExpression and not .Parse.

Comment: There is a single error "Incorrect syntax near )."

Comment: Pretty sure it's a bug. Consider upvoting here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38694355-microsoft-sqlserver-transactsql-scriptdom-tsqlpars